# R: Get Coordinates of Alphahull Points sorted, so that lines() can plot the alphahull

Tags: r

I created a schematic map of my fields in R (using the `sf` package), and want to add some grass symbols to the permanent grassland areas. I have already added symbols for leaf trees, coniferous trees and oaks to the plot by using the `TeachingDemos::my.symbols()` function, which I really like. However, the grassland symbol is more complicated, and I struggle handing it over to `TeachingDemos::my.symbols()`. I would need a matrix with a column for the x-coordinates and a column for the y-coordinates, with the lines representing the order of the points from where to where to draw the lines. E.g. the symbol for coniferous trees is simple:

```
X11(width = 10, height = 10)
plot(x = 1:10, y = 1:10, type = "n")
ms.cfs <- as.matrix(data.frame(x = c(-0.84, 0, 0.84), y = c(-0.4, 0.67, -0.4)))
library(TeachingDemos)
my.symbols(x = 5.5, y = 5.5, ysize = 3, symb = ms.cfs)
```

Now I found [here](https://https//icon-icons.com/icon/grass/4632) a symbol for grass, that I like: [image: grass symbol]. However `TeachingDemos::ms.image` doesn't do the job (it will always use all of the plotting area for the symbol in question. (To double check it, add the following code to the code given above:)

```
library(png)
ms.grass <- readPNG("grass_symbol.png")
my.symbols(x = 2, y = 2, ysize = 1, symb = ms.image(ms.grass, transpose = TRUE))
```

I realized the object `ms.grass` which the `png`-package creates doesn't look too difficult and it should be possible to get the coordinates out there in the same style as they are in the `ms.cfs` object. I do:

```
ms.grass <- ms.grass[,,4]
ms.grass <- t(ms.grass)
ms.grass <- which(ms.grass != 0, arr.ind = TRUE)
ms.grass[,2] <- 49 - ms.grass[,2]
plot(ms.grass)
```

and can clearly see the image, only that there are unnecessary points added:
[image: grass image as points]

If I use the original image in a higher resolution (compare the link (source 1)), the `alphahull` package finds the correct points:

```
library(alphahull)
ms.gs <- ashape(ms.grass, alpha = 0.75)
plot(ms.gs)
```

[image: ahull of grass points]

And with Dario Forentinos Code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72449104/converting-alpha-hulls-to-spatial-polygon/75089615#75089615) I also get the coordinates of the points again:

```
ms.gs1 <- ms.gs$edges[, c("x1", "y1", "x2", "y2")]
ms.gs1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(t(ms.gs1), byrow = TRUE, ncol = 2))
names(ms.gs1) <- c("x", "y")
```

only I can't get them in the right order, so that `lines()` will still yield this shape. (Dario Forentino as well as [Allan Cameron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61973754/extract-multiple-polygons-from-alphahull-in-r) seem to get that right; only I don't need a spatial polygons object, but only the `data.frame`, as e.g. in the `ms.cfs` object provided above.) Does someone know how to do it?

**EDIT:**

Function `aplpack::puticon()` solves the usecase at hand, since it does what `TeachingDemos::my.symbols(symb = TeachingDemos::ms.image())` also is supposed to do. However, it doesn't solve the question presented.